# Adding Fade to My Body Background Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a background body slider which will switch through body backgrounds with 'next' and 'back' buttons. Live example here:

https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/lookbook

This functions perfectly (ignore the large images causing it to load slowly), but I can't seem to add a crossfade effect like on this website:

http://northamerica.triangl.com/pages/lookbook-swimwear

I tried this with CSS `transition: all 0.5s ease-out` but the transition is poor and loaded horribly.

Could anybody please advise where I can add a crossfade to this so that it's like the website above? Thank you for your help and time.

**HTML & jQuery etc.**

```
<!-- Remove header from lookbook page only and add background1 -->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (top.location.pathname === '/lookbook')
{
    jQuery("#root-header-cp-41e961ff2cbb3d4e6ae72927272f2db5").addClass("removeheader");
    jQuery("body").addClass("background1");
}
});
</script>

<!-- Change background -->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1; // current background index
    var max_backgrounds = 3; // number of backgrounds it will work with any number
    jQuery(".next").click(function() {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("background" + current);
        // next background index or first one if it's the last one
        current++;
        if (current > max_backgrounds) {
            current = 1;
        }
        // change background to background1, background2 ...
        jQuery("body").addClass("background" + current);
    });
    jQuery(".back").click(function() {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("background" + current);
        // previous background index or last one if current is the first one
        current--;
        if (current < 1) {
            current = max_backgrounds
        }
        // change background to background1, background2 ...
        jQuery("body").addClass("background" + current);
    });
});
</script>

<!-- Container plus images -->

<div id="toggle" width="100%">
<img src="/media/import/icons/back.png" class="back">
<img src="/media/import/icons/next.png" class="next">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Body background options */

.background1 {
    background: url('/media/import/backgrounds/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background2 {
    background: url('/media/import/backgrounds/background2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background3 {
    background: url('/media/import/backgrounds/background3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Toggle Buttons */

#toggle .next {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
}

#toggle .back {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}

#toggle img {
    margin-top: 400px;
    display: inline;
}

#toggle img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use multiple elements, which are all positioned in the exact same place. All elements must have an `opacity: 0`, except the active one (`opacity: 1`).

When you navigate to the next/previous item, you need to toggle an active class on them, which removes/sets `opacity: 1`

**Simplified example with divs:**

```js
(function () {

        var prevButton = $('.previous'),
            nextButton = $('.next'),
            allImages = $('.background-images li');

        nextButton.click(function(e) {

            // Find the active element
            activeElement = $('li.bg-active');
            // remove the 'bg-active'-class from this element
            activeElement.removeClass('bg-active');

            // if current element is the last one, make sure to add 'bg-active'-class to the very first element.
            if (activeElement[0] === allImages.last()[0]){
                allImages.first().addClass('bg-active');
            } else {
                // Add 'bg-active'-class to the next element
                activeElement.next().addClass('bg-active');
            }

        });

        prevButton.click(function(e) {

            activeElement = $('li.bg-active');
            activeElement.removeClass('bg-active');

            // if current element is the first one, make sure to add 'bg-active'-class to the very lst element.
            if (activeElement[0] === allImages.first()[0]){
                allImages.last().addClass('bg-active');
            } else {
                // add 'bg-active'-class to the previous element
                activeElement.prev().addClass('bg-active');
            }
        });



    })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        ul {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        li {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }
        .bg {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        }
        .bg-active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .bg1 {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .bg2 {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .bg3 {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="previous">previous</a>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>

<ul class="background-images">
    <li class="bg bg1 bg-active"></li>
    <li class="bg bg2"></li>
    <li class="bg bg3"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> `#Crossfade img {
>       position:absolute;
>       left:0;
>       -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
>       -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
>       -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
>       transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
>   }`

This should give you the crossfade that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling classes you could just swap out the image, here's a quick proof of concept you can run in your console:

```
jQuery("body").css({'background-image':'url(/media/import/backgrounds/background3.jpg)', 'transition':'all 0.5s ease-out'});
```

Adapting this for your code would look something like:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(".next").click(function() {
    current++;
    if (current > max_backgrounds) {
        current = 1;
    }
    jQuery("body").css({'background-image':'url(/media/import/backgrounds/background' + current + '.jpg');
});
jQuery(".back").click(function() {
    current--;
    if (current < 1) {
        current = max_backgrounds
    }
    jQuery("body").css({'background-image':'url(/media/import/backgrounds/background' + current + '.jpg');
});
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There many ways you can about this and [this gentleman has showcase many of them](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

Some pointers:

The page you've given as an example loads every image when the page loads.
Performance wise, you don't want that. If you're going to do such an effect, make sure you load the images only when they actually required.

They achieve the effect by pilling all images on top of each other, then animating the opacity in/out when clicking the arrows.
Since they all have `position:absolute`, you'll get the crossfade effect you wish for.